# Multi-Step Journey Not Sending Emails After a Decision Split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a multi-step journey where if a contact chooses to opt-in to our emails, they will receive an email after a few minutes. I created it using a Cloudpage as a data entry source, followed by a Decision Split where Path 1 is where those that opted to receive our emails (the rule for the Decision Split is "Opt-In equal True"), will then receive an email. And nothing happens to the remainder, they just exit after a day. I have used Journey Data for this.

For the data extension, the attribute for the Opt-In is Text.

I have tested it with multiple emails, but none of them have processed and I have not received an email so far. Has anyone experienced a similar issue?